# Berkeley DB: Locking a record without reading it

Tags: language-agnostic, locking, berkeley-db

I use a Berkeley database with transactions in an environment with multiple threads but only a single process.

Since I only have a single process, I'd like to cache the parsed representation of the data from some records so that I don't have to re-parse it unnecessarily every time I access it, but if I do that naïvely without issuing any database operation when accessing the cached data, I will clearly not be following the locking protocol properly, leading transactions not to be properly isolated from each other.

I could obviously fix this by just running a `get` operation on a record I intend to use during a transaction, but that seems unnecessary in terms of I/O and also just ugly since I don't actually need to re-read the data. Is there a way to do locking "as if" I had issued a `get` operation?

Likewise, is there a way to do the corresponding write-locks for `put` operations, since I need to do them before modifying the cached data (which needs to be done before serializing the data in order to actually `put` it)?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a (parsed) cache consistent with an underlying database store isn't trivial.
Have you considered saving the already parsed data directly in BerkeleyDB to remove parsing overhead? Yes this involves a schema change, and may also require more disk space.

BerkeleyDB goes to some lengths to minimize I/O within the mpool and should be near optimal for a properly configured database.

If you are using transactions, then isolation between get/put operations is handled during the transaction commit without a need for additional locking. Yes the commit may may fail or clobber another commit. Add an additional locking layer (using BerkeleyDB locking subsystem or anything you wish) on the put record key if you need exclusivity while updating a record.